# How does Function App Host know an Event has been pushed to the Event Hub to invoke the associated Event Hub Trigger?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub

- Does Function App do 'long polling' or 'loop with delay' behind the scene to check if there is a new Event?
- Is there a notification mechanism built behind the scenes by Azure team to let Function App Host know when a new Event is pushed to the Event Hub?
- How is Microsoft able to bear either of the above steps operation cost?

Answer (score 2):

There is a detailed article about Function scaling: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/event-driven-scaling

Gist of it: (when running in Consumption tier), the Scale Controller is hosted and run by the Service, your instance only gets started when the SC detects new work and only then your billing starts.